# Are there any Perl options for company mode?

Tags: company-mode, completion, perl

The only code completion I've found was PlSense but as far as I can see the only options with Emacs using autocomplete among other dependencies. While I don't mind that if I can try to stick to doing my completions with as little dependency purpose replication as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wrote a company back-end for PlSense. You can find it [here](https://github.com/CeleritasCelery/company-plsense). Note that it is still very new but it works great for me!

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I'm installing it now.